# Parsing plain text to js array - add separator to the second element

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, split

I'm searching solution how to parse plain text to the js array. I have already found some scheme in which i want to do this, but kind of stuck.

**Part of plain text:**

```
2017-11-08 09:43:49,153 [INFO ] root: {\"methodId\":6,\"requestBody\":{},\"token\":\"XXXX\"}2017-11-08 09:53:02,293 [INFO ] root: {\"methodId\":6,\"requestBody\":{},\"token\":\"XXXX\"}2017-11-08 09:53:02,355 [INFO ] root: {\"methodId\":6,\"requestBody\":{},\"token\":\"XXXX\"}
```

**Expected result**

```
const arr = [
    '2017-11-08 09:43:49,153 [INFO ] root: {\"methodId\":6,\"requestBody\":{},\"token\":\"XXXX\"}',
    '2017-11-08 09:53:02,293 [INFO ] root: {\"methodId\":6,\"requestBody\":{},\"token\":\"XXXX\"}',
    '2017-11-08 09:53:02,355 [INFO ] root: {\"methodId\":6,\"requestBody\":{},\"token\":\"XXXX\"}'
]
```

**RegEx Pattern:**

```
/}\d{4}-\d{2}/
```

Each chunk ends by closing object "}" and starting new date "YYYY-MM".

**Problem**

```
plainText.split(/}\d{4}-\d{2}/)
```

If i split it this way, it always "eats" my separator. Is there some way to split text and add founded separator to the second element from the splited pair? Then i could just add "}" to the first one and remove "}" from the second one. It's solution I'm thinking about, but maybe you can suggest something even better.

Comment: Where does this messed up plain text come from in the first place?

Comment: `s.split(/\b(?=\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s+[\d:,]+\s+\[INFO ]\s+root:)/).filter(Boolean)`. Shorten the pattern if the requirements can be lax (depends on the scenario, it can even be `/\b(?=\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s/` if the date strings do not appear in the JSON data). See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/6ZPbkW/1/).

Comment: @melpomene It's response from the api I'm working with. 
I have no control over the form in which it gets the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the JSON data does not contain datetime-like substrings, you may use

```
s.split(/\b(?=\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s/).filter(Boolean)
```

Or a more verbose (to play it safer):

```
s.split(/\b(?=\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s+[\d:,]+\s+\[INFO ]\s+root:)/).filter(Boolean)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TuI5a5/1/)

The point is to match the datetime-like string but not consume it, thus, the whole pattern is wrapped within a positive lookahead `(?=...)` construct.

**Longer pattern details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?=` - start of the positive lookahead pattern

  - `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}` - date-like string (4 digits-2 digits-2 digits)
  - `\s+` -  1 or more whitespaces
  - `[\d:,]+` - 1 or more digits, `:` or/and `,`
  - `\s+` -  1 or more whitespaces
  - `\[INFO ]` - an `[INFO ]` substring
  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `root:` - `root:` substring
- `)` - end of the lookahead